# google gcm "raw_data" payload for desktop chrome 50 beta

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging, payload, service-worker, raw-data

I am trying to send a and read message payload using the google GCM mechanism.
To send the data I am using the instructions found under "Web Push" in: 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption?hl=en
where it is instructed, that until full support by chrome is available, the payload can be sent using "raw_data" which needs to be base64 encripted.

to display the data I am ussing chorome 50Beta, since it is supposed to support payloads. 
but when the 'push' event is fired, the service-worker event.data is null.

Is there a live web example of chrome push messaging payload out there?

Answer (score 1):

You could use my [web-push Node.js library](https://github.com/marco-c/web-push). I've recently added support for Chrome 50.

I've just released the version 2 of the library with support for payloads on Chrome 50 and I've updated the [ServiceWorker Cookbook](https://serviceworke.rs/) to use it.

You can use the demos on that website (in particular the [Push Payload](https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload.html) one).

Comment: Thank you, did you use "raw_data" or encoded "data" for sending?.
I've tried your demo page, the "Request sending notification button" generates  a 503 error.
https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload_demo.html
but, this demo does work :https://serviceworke.rs/push-get-payload_demo.html

Comment: I haven't updated the ServiceWorker Cookbook yet, there's a PR to do that: https://github.com/mozilla/serviceworker-cookbook/pull/219.
I'm using `raw_data`.

Comment: @Marco Does your library support receipts or do you need to have an XMPP server? Also, does XMPP support raw_data?

Comment: It doesn't support receipts yet. As far as I know they aren't supported by any standard Web Push service, so there's no way to use them.